# atmega16 in Arduino Board

Tags: hardware

I had a very common question. Why a additional MEGA used in most of the Arduino Boards. Arduino board Mega2560 also have a MEGA16U2 controller on board which i think is used for programming via USB. Is there any other specific usage of atmega16 on arduino board.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an ATmegaU2, which has USB hardware and handles the USB communication. It passes the hex file on to the bootloader in the main microcontroller. That is its only job.

Comment: as i can see its ATMEGA16U2. It handle USB communication means it simply convert a USB to serial?

Comment: That's what I said, in a different way.